# How to get Heap segment virtual address

Tags: windows, heap-memory

As you know, we are able get process heaps using `GetProcessHeaps` function, but how can i get address of heap segment address that belongs to each of heaps?

Thanks!

Comment: what you mean under *heap segment* ? for get full information about heap, it regions (== segment ?), blocks - use `HeapWalk` function. all information in `PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY`

Comment: @RbMm hi, i mean i need to find all `HEAP_SEGMENT`'s in memory. Every heap has it's own memory page with that structure. Unfortunately, `PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY` doesn't link to these pages

Comment: i not understand what you mean under *HEAP_SEGMENT's in memory*. `PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY` containing **complete** info about heap memory

Comment: if you mean [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/HEAP_SEGMENT.html) - the heap handle itself actually pointed to this. if you have heap handle - it pointer. and all information exist in `Region` member of `PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY` if the `wFlags` member specifies `PROCESS_HEAP_REGION`.